# "printf" printing twice despite being called only once

Tags: c, io

I'm almost ashamed to ask such a basic question but this makes no sense. Why does the question print twice ? I've tried adding a `sleep` to make sure it's not the enter key staying pressed too long, but it still did that. Note that it only happens on the second call onwards, which is definitely a clue.

```c
char question() {
    char response = ' ';
    while(response != '+' && response != '-' && response != '=') {
        printf("Respond with + or - or  = : ");
        scanf("%c", &response);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: This is the infamous newline character, that is in fact a character in the input stream/

Comment: So scanf reads the `newline` from my **previous** input !?

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &response);` Put a space before `%c` to skip leading whitespace.

Comment: No, `scanf` reads the input stream, the previous time it first time it read the character, the second time the newline character as in the "enter key" you pressed.